# OLS regression with multiple dependent variables that are correlated with each other

Tags: multivariate-analysis, least-squares, econometrics, multivariate-regression

Suppose I want to see the impact of an explanatory variable $X$ on two different dependent variables: $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. Suppose also that I find that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are correlated.

Assuming that all other necessary assumptions for OLS regression are satisfied, can I assess the two impacts on individuals $i$ by just running OLS on

$Y_{1i} = \beta_0+\beta_1X_i+\beta_2Y_{2i}+\epsilon_i$

and

$Y_{2i} = \delta_0+\delta_1X_i+\delta_2Y_{1i}+v_i$

?

Comment: Did you intend to have $\delta_0$ as the intercept in the $Y_2$ equation? What is the relationship between the epsilons in the two equations?

Comment: My bad - yes it was meant to be a delta0 and a vi.

Comment: What do you know about how the $\epsilon_i$ and $\upsilon_i$ might be correlated?  That determines how to proceed.  For instance, do you know their correlations independently of these data?  Can you assume their correlations are unvarying?

Comment: For my purposes, they would likely be correlated.

Comment: Right--that's not what I'm asking.  I'm asking for more specific, quantitative information or assumptions about that correlation.  Moreover, do you really intend to be regressing the $Y_{1i}$ and $Y_{2i}$ against each other?  What sense does that make?  Isn't this some kind of typographical error in the formulas?